# Prove that if $abc\ne0$ and $ab+bc+ac=0$ then $a+b+c\ne0$

Tags: contest-math

I tried to do proof  by contradiction, but problem is how to get from $ab+bc+ac$ to $a+b+c$

Assuming $a+b+c=0$
my approachs:

1. Adding $ab+ac+bc=0$ and $a+b+c=0$ and try to factor
2. Deriving $$a^2+ab+ac=0\\ac+bc+c^2=0\\ab+b^2+bc=0$$ and trying to derive something but nothing useful.

Please just some hint will do the help to me

Comment: I believe that we should add the assumption that these are real numbers (otherwise the roots of $X^3-1$ are a counterexample).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked for a hint.  Try thinking about $(a+b+c)(a+b+c)$

Comment: okay I get $a+b+c=0$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2=0$ how do I go about proving that it $\implies a=b=c=0$ ?

Comment: @user182452 we have $x+y+z = 0$ with $x,y,z \geq 0$.  What do we know about $x,y,z?$

Comment: of course duh, finally understood thank you all :)

Answer (score 4):

If $ab+bc+ac=a+b+c=0$, then $a,b,c$ are the three roots of a cubic equation $X^3 - abc=0$.  But any nonzero number has two non-real cube roots, so $abc=0$—assuming that at least two of $a,b,c$ are real.